# JS calculated value is not shown

Tags: javascript, php

I have developed a small page where an user can add 2 items (bron / afzuigunit) and see what the total cost of this configuration will be.
[It can be found here](https://torza.nl/swift/mach_swift_cut_xp_detail.php)

The 2 options

```
<tr>
    <td>Plasma bron</td>
    <td width="20px"></td>
    <td><select id="bron" onchange="calculate()">
      <option value="0_0">Kies uw plasmabron</option>
      <option value="Geen_0">Geen</option>
      <option value="PowerMax 45XP_50">PowerMax 45XP</option>
      <option value="PowerMax 65_100">PowerMax 65</option>
      <option value="PowerMax 85_150">PowerMax 85</option>
      <option value="PowerMax 105_200">PowerMax 105</option>
      <option value="PowerMax 125_250">PowerMax 125</option>
    </select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Afzuigunit</td>
    <td width="20px"></td>
    <td><select id="afzuig" onchange="calculate()">
      <option value="0_0">Kies uw afzuiging</option>
      <option value="Geen_0">Geen / waterbak</option>
      <option value="Donaldson_1000">Donaldson</option>
    </select></td>
</tr>
```

I have used `_` to use the correct value in my JS code

```
<script>
function calculate()
{
   var bron = (document.getElementById("bron").value).split('_');
   var afzuig = (document.getElementById("afzuig").value).split('_');

    document.getElementById('verkoop').value = ((20000 * 1) + (bron[1] * 1) + (afzuig[1] * 1));
}
</script>
```

This part should display the correct price

```
<h3 class="my-4 text-center text-success">Uw prijs: € <span id="verkoop">20.000</span>,-</h3>
```

For some reason the is no change in price when an option is selected. Also no error is shown. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're not changing the value.  You're changing the inner text of the span.  Instead of .value, use .innerText

```
document.getElementById('verkoop').innerText = //same code here
```

Comment: Why the downvote?  If you don't tell me, then I won't learn and I'll make the same mistake in the future.